# Can we change date in text format to datepicker in Gantt Chart from highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I have a requirement where I need to show date-picker in Gantt chart.

[Instead of highlighted text I want date-picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFyN8.png)

I know if I click on the date text in the chart I can see date-picker but my for requirement want to see date-picker only instead of date text in blue color.

Please let me know if that is possible to implement.

I have tried all the properties from [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/rangeSelector)
But I am not getting result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set it using the API but it is possible to get to it, but you need a little more knowledge of the library itself.

First, you need to override the function responsible for hiding inputs:

```js
Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.hideInput = Highcharts.noop;
```

and then in the callback function `chart.events.render()` call the `rangeSelecotr` object the `showInput()` method to enable their visibility. In addition, you can hide the text below them and move them slightly apart:

```js
chart: {
  events: {
    render() {
      const rg = this.rangeSelector;

      rg.showInput('min');
      rg.showInput('max');
      rg.inputGroup.css({ opacity: 0 });
      rg.minInput.style.left = `${rg.minInput.style.left.match(/\d+/)[0] - 10}px`;
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3ohwusm8/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

**React** demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-forked-lvgs24?file=/index.js

Comment: Thanks Michal,

Yes it works for me in plain javascript project. 
I am having react component and I am new to highcharts. 
How can I set this below property in my react project?

Highcharts.RangeSelector.prototype.hideInput = Highcharts.noop;

Comment: In a very simple way, after importing Highcharts overwrite its functionality. I added domo to the answer.

Comment: Will it work for Gantt chart as well?
And I am using React + typescript
And can we change date format there in the date picker. I want something like
22-Jun-2023

Comment: Yep, it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-typescript-custom-wrap-lkzrdq

Comment: As for the question about changing the format, because it is an HTML input of date type, it is a more general question and there are many topics on this topic on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: I am getting this below error 
Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type '{ render(): void; }'.ts(2339)
my code is just like yours 
Instead of functional component im using class based component

Comment: Can you reproduce it in an online editor then?

Comment: Hey Michal,
I tried to reproduce but it works with react-typescript app. Here you can see https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sbnr4f?file=src%2FApp.tsx
Actually I am building mendix widget using react, typescript and gantt chart highcharts. 
Not sure whats happening but if I add events to chart property I get this error.
//
Property 'rangeSelector' does not exist on type '{ render(): void; }'.ts(2339)
//
If you know any alternatives or fix for this one let me know